# geom_ribbon for multiple densities in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scaling, area, density-plot

I have a data frame (aa) with daily values of 7 variables and I want to create the density plot of all the variable in one plot using the ggplot in R.

```
date                1       2      3       4         5        6      7
1/1/1951 1:00   576.568 308.596 501.752 359.868 772.522 475.146 307.991
1/2/1951 1:00   722.986 461.295 652.33  525.561 1806.75 724.128 460.697
1/3/1951 1:00   859.542 582.949 910.248 642.133 2388.73 959.896 579.396
1/4/1951 1:00   1136.49 704.732 1047.04 1304.73 2619.04 1545.61 690.574
1/5/1951 1:00   1747.84 769.764 1099.24 1828.5  2695.6  2052.11 790.35
1/6/1951 1:00   1842.66 811.765 1130.44 2031.97 2747.14 2532.89 860.417
1/7/1951 1:00   2734.15 895.825 1158.42 2145.6  2772.58 2826.31 944.181
1/8/1951 1:00   2870.02 996.17  1159.5  2123.04 2773.86 3385.17 1055.53
1/9/1951 1:00   3687.38 1021.61 1150.51 2096.66 2812.93 3579.46 1064.43
1/10/1951 1:00  3704.4  1015.38 1133.83 2064.84 3338.98 3649.31 1183.86
1/11/1951 1:00  4270.37 1007.37 1121.8  2018.4  3299.18 3702.44 1459.35
1/12/1951 1:00  4477.54 990.477 1094.73 1985.98 3269.85 4044.5  1638.76
1/13/1951 1:00  4447.05 969.607 1068.21 1949.35 3179.74 4154.53 1726.56
1/14/1951 1:00  4400.13 985.999 1599    1944.67 3185.36 4216.58 1704.72
1/15/1951 1:00  4332.73 971.912 2050.99 2405.2  3274.99 4204.33 1698.51
1/16/1951 1:00  4249.38 944.5   2080.25 2578.95 3391.08 4142.77 1712.02
1/17/1951 1:00  4152.52 920.435 2054.55 2653.13 3541.91 4208.52 1678.24
1/18/1951 1:00  4127.45 893.521 2169.34 2732.53 3563.56 4303.28 1664.81
1/19/1951 1:00  4386.13 863.506 2138    2810.65 3551.63 4205.68 1635.35
1/20/1951 1:00  4266.45 833.389 2098.66 2918.06 3626.92 4542.01 1600.13
1/21/1951 1:00  4123.47 803.421 2054    2944.82 3602.07 4501.44 1589.96
1/22/1951 1:00  3985.95 773.803 2370.33 2988.91 3535.31 4395.38 1684.4
1/23/1951 1:00  4022.89 744.697 3314.27 2965.02 3482.09 4359.78 1758.83
1/24/1951 1:00  4081.97 716.225 3497.79 2924.84 3567.54 4564.74 1709.34
1/25/1951 1:00  4062.92 688.476 3472.63 2935.65 3502.1  4548.38 1680.46
1/26/1951 1:00  4365.36 661.515 3380.87 3481.96 3440.78 4987.91 1637.77
1/27/1951 1:00  4401.38 635.384 3287.63 3995.07 3437.95 5059.32 1604.2
1/28/1951 1:00  4269.47 610.107 3192.09 3945.04 3722.05 4953.97 1552.9
1/29/1951 1:00  4318.51 585.697 3094.34 3915.98 3702.45 4895.55 1502.28
1/30/1951 1:00  4298.75 562.154 2994.88 3880.55 3636.89 4766.2  1451.75
1/31/1951 1:00  4153.07 539.473 2894.43 3799.82 3565.1  4644.76 1531.08
2/1/1951 1:00   4003.85 517.64  2793.79 3710.46 3485.51 4580.68 1748.19
2/2/1951 1:00   3857.05 915.839 2693.67 3623.19 3398.42 4543.95 1858.94
2/3/1951 1:00   3713.03 902.46  2608.46 3519.39 3311    4452.38 1851.69
2/4/1951 1:00   3572.17 865.735 3865.87 3435.52 3231.97 4317.65 1814.48
2/5/1951 1:00   3434.84 1153.22 4238.76 3407.45 3129.51 4184.76 1775.47
2/6/1951 1:00   3301.26 1106.52 4103.02 3497.4  3055.22 4172.17 1756.6
2/7/1951 1:00   3172.63 1061.36 3956.05 3673.07 2968.45 4302.39 1716.4
2/8/1951 1:00   3079.31 1018.01 4103.28 3630.38 3435.38 4536.9  1669.38
2/9/1951 1:00   2959.4  980.38  4208.58 3518.13 3605.31 4451.53 1746.94
2/10/1951 1:00  2844.15 940.297 4190.15 3388.06 3468.35 4382.59 1691.15
2/11/1951 1:00  2732.83 901.835 4119.65 3292.29 3845.2  4349.97 1634.61
2/12/1951 1:00  2634.55 864.93  4204.1  3171.04 3858.71 4273.37 1597.97
2/13/1951 1:00  2540.9  830.727 4192.34 3047.67 4388.68 4170.63 2284.54
2/14/1951 1:00  2529.75 896.13  4094.57 2928.25 5056.55 4161.73 2458.95
2/15/1951 1:00  2483.45 1214.75 3977.09 2812.77 5601.96 4061.48 2382.13
2/16/1951 1:00  2384    1314.73 3859.21 2701.17 5968.48 3950.86 3140.67
2/17/1951 1:00  2288.75 1274.76 3740.11 2593.42 6033.75 3834.06 3194.2
2/18/1951 1:00  2196.63 1239.29 3620.01 2489.48 5938.22 3730.9  3097.74
2/19/1951 1:00  2108.71 1207.04 3510.97 2389.31 5807.13 3637.96 3174.11
2/20/1951 1:00  2029.62 1168.64 3434.68 2292.85 5671.36 3540.38 3080.33
2/21/1951 1:00  1953.52 1495.14 3404.76 2200.02 5612.84 3431.11 2977.1
2/22/1951 1:00  1877.59 2010.5  3344.68 2110.75 5475.63 3313.23 2875.18
2/23/1951 1:00  1804.35 2375.9  3251.89 2024.93 5329.19 3282.22 2774.5
2/24/1951 1:00  1732.6  2412.77 3150.66 2034.99 5179.73 3456.21 2675.38
2/25/1951 1:00  1701.74 2436.28 3088.83 2513.05 5239.82 3454.15 2578.02
2/26/1951 1:00  1727.88 2377.25 2999.05 2798.06 5264.78 3709.65 2482.93
2/27/1951 1:00  1669.38 2402.1  2903.54 2965.21 5553.4  3653.49 2390.28
2/28/1951 1:00  1608.28 2345.84 2830.42 2996.06 5478.35 3560.17 2300.54
3/1/1951 1:00   1574.09 2285.2  2738.14 3053.62 5352.85 3605.94 2216.72
3/2/1951 1:00   1568.13 2220.31 2644.64 2985.46 5227.08 3699.48 2129.27
3/3/1951 1:00   1647.75 2220.27 2631.15 2969.02 5213.33 3721.7  2044.68
3/4/1951 1:00   1719.77 2521.67 2670.33 3164.43 5160.05 3681.58 1964.03
3/5/1951 1:00   1704.79 2626.48 2704.3  3173.32 5399.89 3610.76 1889.66
3/6/1951 1:00   1639.59 2741.6  2668.98 3236.33 5554.96 3528.92 1818.41
3/7/1951 1:00   1575.53 2677.43 2704.18 3341.03 5592.91 3469.95 1750.35
3/8/1951 1:00   1513.84 3081.42 2750.38 3387.48 5541.88 3409.68 1680.34
3/9/1951 1:00   1454.16 3035.34 2764.71 3473.48 5517.83 3340.67 1612.23
3/10/1951 1:00  1396.52 2988.29 2711.31 3448.16 5614.53 3250.09 1549.71
3/11/1951 1:00  1340.85 3336.91 2698.67 3492.85 5522.72 3160.29 1504.31
3/12/1951 1:00  1287.2  3368.07 2663.92 3484.74 5410.01 3063.21 1467.34
3/13/1951 1:00  1235.86 3346.46 2599.99 3447.85 5289.24 2997.02 1435.41
3/14/1951 1:00  1192.06 3742.42 2533.14 3406.32 5154.86 2901.11 1417.03
3/15/1951 1:00  1167.73 4132.53 2463.68 3331.86 5014.21 2808.8  1405.8
3/16/1951 1:00  1295.27 4405.71 2391.41 3253.14 4868.89 2710.32 1392.99
3/17/1951 1:00  1618.42 4427.48 2316.29 3170.24 4732.69 2608.73 1373.93
3/18/1951 1:00  1559.84 4442.58 2239.86 3087.54 4608.15 2509.65 1348.4
3/19/1951 1:00  1502.9  4696.88 2162.9  3004.81 4457.99 2412.95 1327.24
3/20/1951 1:00  1447.55 4767.77 2086.49 2918.91 4299.06 2318.83 1272.94
3/21/1951 1:00  1393.54 4734    2019.74 2831.26 4142.57 2242.03 1276.85
3/22/1951 1:00  1341.04 4692.49 1959.31 2745.44 3991.74 2190    1245.43
3/23/1951 1:00  1289.98 4630.91 1895.69 2665.02 3841.69 2113.67 1200.63
3/24/1951 1:00  1240.42 4589.67 1826.32 2564.35 3695.19 2032.02 1151.92
3/25/1951 1:00  1195.7  4594.68 1758.67 2466.22 3552.06 1952.83 1108.28
3/26/1951 1:00  1159.06 4543.89 1690.77 2372.2  3436.21 1893.66 1072.04
3/27/1951 1:00  1145.87 4434.54 1623.81 2281.07 3308.64 1823.82 1053.01
3/28/1951 1:00  1158.77 4320.49 1559.12 2196.58 3178.24 1905.79 1071.73
3/29/1951 1:00  1144.67 4202.17 1496.77 2119.89 3056.39 1905.91 1202.11
3/30/1951 1:00  1169.91 4077.59 1436.54 2048.02 2938.67 1863.56 1227.16
3/31/1951 1:00  1812.98 3947.1  1378.53 1989.09 2824.59 1889.91 1177.6
4/1/1951 1:00   1865.61 3814.54 1322.83 1942.43 2714.82 1828.26 1130.36
4/2/1951 1:00   1880.82 3681.54 1270.61 1874.94 2610.78 1772.37 1085.31
4/3/1951 1:00   1875.71 3549.85 1219.25 1814.91 2515.79 1717.05 1064.22
4/4/1951 1:00   1852.95 3441.96 1174.54 1754.13 2424.83 1672.71 1148.52
4/5/1951 1:00   1823.04 3312.73 1150.92 1686.87 2346.9  1916.25 1175.51
4/6/1951 1:00   1788.45 3424.52 1107.59 1622.21 2274.12 2001.31 1327.16
4/7/1951 1:00   1755.09 3390.87 1064.25 1560.85 2202.44 1935.57 1300.41
4/8/1951 1:00   1723.22 3308.63 1035.33 1500.06 2132.47 1882.89 1725.13
4/9/1951 1:00   1689.11 3495.84 997.53  1440.55 2068.17 1898.3  1703.47
4/10/1951 1:00  1658.82 3431.23 1032.74 1383.38 1986.15 1964.13 1663.5
4/11/1951 1:00  1629.97 3964.34 1029.15 1329.29 1905.02 1902.88 1802.32
4/12/1951 1:00  1598.96 3958.32 1009.02 1285.82 1828.44 1838.5  1786.33
4/13/1951 1:00  1560.68 3836.09 1007.55 1234.12 1754.68 1783.13 1810.27
4/14/1951 1:00  1517.77 3715.66 997.538 1245.67 1685.86 1718.58 1803.11
4/15/1951 1:00  1476.25 3595.59 972.362 1235.17 1621.62 1655.1  1745.61
4/16/1951 1:00  1440.83 3475.52 947.23  1200.96 1560.92 1593.27 1684.32
4/17/1951 1:00  1404.89 3361.25 914.863 1160.45 1504.27 1533.62 1634.78
4/18/1951 1:00  1373.95 3245.87 882.695 1165.72 1450.55 1476.49 1587.29
4/19/1951 1:00  1346.33 3144.21 851.48  1222.47 1400.78 1425.16 1539.01
4/20/1951 1:00  1326.58 3070.07 825.579 1192.75 1352.88 1380.79 1496.15
4/21/1951 1:00  1313.58 2957.91 799.894 1279.43 1304.74 1375.75 1467.54
4/22/1951 1:00  1295.72 2858.02 780.357 1278.21 1257.36 1329.1  1447.8
4/23/1951 1:00  1290.81 2794.22 755.867 1692.37 1219.04 1296.83 1470.15
4/24/1951 1:00  1284.3  2731.48 741.104 1763.2  1213.48 1372.8  1496.9
4/25/1951 1:00  1312.79 2629.26 732.116 1764.69 1202.94 1411.4  1484.06
4/26/1951 1:00  1280.24 2547.8  734.836 1705.97 1423.37 1390.16 1479.25
4/27/1951 1:00  1231.06 2476.66 749.586 1648.91 1542.41 1341.19 1523.21
4/28/1951 1:00  1204.23 2401.36 769.556 1635.77 1494.66 1304.07 1568.9
4/29/1951 1:00  1256.4  2326.5  743.761 1700.3  1482.53 1277.8  1653.51
4/30/1951 1:00  1228.98 2366.87 723.332 1733.35 1599.09 1256.08 1655.35
5/1/1951 1:00   1232.3  2325.47 699.928 2318.56 1544    1232.58 1660.23
5/2/1951 1:00   1265.11 2234.34 681.914 2419.03 1482.98 1212.6  1675.77
5/3/1951 1:00   1248.22 2153.43 675.823 2379.94 1446.54 1185.34 1686.94
5/4/1951 1:00   1337.7  2079.83 670.847 2392.08 1395.88 1156.82 1698.45
5/5/1951 1:00   1306.61 2019.09 672.758 2466.25 1346.6  1136.58 1710.61
5/6/1951 1:00   1306.49 1970.78 700.209 2655.81 1295.43 1128.42 1698.08
5/7/1951 1:00   1309.95 1932.32 882.106 2674.44 1248.17 1129.06 1689.33
5/8/1951 1:00   1272.11 1889.79 909.731 2641.26 1206.5  1127.26 1676.88
5/9/1951 1:00   1244.76 1874.85 929.057 2723.38 1161.74 1133.94 1668.98
5/10/1951 1:00  1198.68 1882.87 906.422 2773.55 1142.75 1160.08 1658.15
5/11/1951 1:00  1160.28 1923.64 883.694 2729.87 1304.01 1193.74 1636.8
5/12/1951 1:00  1164.25 1890.92 880 2833.58 1261.43 1197.94 1596.65
5/13/1951 1:00  1259.59 1839.77 1006.3  3121.41 1221.17 1178.36 1569.62
5/14/1951 1:00  1214.37 1806.38 1139.01 3055.57 1339.85 1180.08 1531.61
5/15/1951 1:00  1183    1742.32 1514.41 2979.32 1382.48 1223.9  1561.12
5/16/1951 1:00  1159.61 1677.67 1709.11 2925.61 1333.32 1275.86 1599.04
5/17/1951 1:00  1149.81 1631.52 1804.58 2883.21 1298.32 1334.42 1643.99
5/18/1951 1:00  1128.56 1612.8  1780.06 2933.64 1269.32 1385.4  1741.65
5/19/1951 1:00  1115.82 1583.65 1749.24 2872.47 1259.52 1443.94 1814.02
5/20/1951 1:00  1116.03 1604.84 1767.84 2777.15 1236.89 1596.69 1825.09
5/21/1951 1:00  1134.75 1703.42 2013.04 2705.05 1268.37 1565.95 1853.67
5/22/1951 1:00  1122.38 1679.7  2049.85 2623.92 1327.74 1619.07 1806.14
5/23/1951 1:00  1108.9  1800.42 2032.87 2545.06 1459.69 1797.12 1748.84
5/24/1951 1:00  1086.38 1785.76 2031.06 2464.62 1451.84 1806.26 1686.03
5/25/1951 1:00  1074.68 1774.78 2061.98 2395.28 1418.96 1758.22 1624.42
5/26/1951 1:00  1167.38 1739.84 2156.03 2323.39 1390    1709.5  1568.7
5/27/1951 1:00  1166.05 1804.56 2339.12 2238.41 1609.57 1664.23 1515.6
5/28/1951 1:00  1166.96 1936.75 2323.81 2150.81 1638.19 1634.7  1463.76
5/29/1951 1:00  1150.97 1899.51 2329.38 2133.96 1610.33 1615.67 1410.4
5/30/1951 1:00  1171.27 1947.8  2536.99 2146.59 1624.47 1606.06 1361.94
5/31/1951 1:00  1166.67 2194.86 2508.85 2237.88 1575.08 1634.12 1320.08
6/1/1951 1:00   1141.49 2228.97 2434.56 2323.28 1526.3  1661.63 1284.83
6/2/1951 1:00   1120.47 2175.77 2371.56 2267.76 1487.86 1747.76 1256.68
6/3/1951 1:00   1093.94 2171.73 2318.04 2278.99 1474.29 1733.02 1250.33
6/4/1951 1:00   1065.52 2137.24 2263.77 2199.86 1497.28 1713.74 1209.63
6/5/1951 1:00   1041.89 2136.09 2190.93 2121.43 1457.82 1683.18 1201.05
6/6/1951 1:00   1011.35 2136.3  2129.71 2044.39 1444.52 1646.91 1178.4
6/7/1951 1:00   975.028 2145.79 2074.18 1971.57 1448.25 1618.44 1153.39
6/8/1951 1:00   940.422 2114.38 2026.68 1909.96 1458.49 1591.83 1115.06
6/9/1951 1:00   909.511 2060.67 1957.48 1874.84 1496.27 1663.22 1120.41
6/10/1951 1:00  881.323 2011.8  1890.22 1826.43 1534.7  1771.82 1111.26
6/11/1951 1:00  855.554 1962.46 1832.95 1777.2  1593.66 1868.05 1115.46
6/12/1951 1:00  828.964 1909.71 1778.42 1722.21 1636.95 1793.37 1075.06
6/13/1951 1:00  804.086 1859.22 1712    1670.6  1632.44 1722.44 1046.34
6/14/1951 1:00  778.927 1804.78 1651.35 1628.33 1660.17 1657.77 1106.06
6/15/1951 1:00  754.193 1751.86 1598.2  1762.41 1738.57 1609.42 1069.42
6/16/1951 1:00  731.139 1701.25 1555.76 1843.26 1765.32 1556.76 1035.4
6/17/1951 1:00  710.103 1659.92 1498.78 1791.43 1784.72 1579.74 1002.95
6/18/1951 1:00  703.879 1603.93 1603.34 1769.58 2015.57 1601.42 997.783
6/19/1951 1:00  691.781 1548.96 1559.46 1717.57 2050.61 1540.37 970.923
6/20/1951 1:00  1059.58 1494.3  1522.58 1671.23 2051.55 1481.78 939.208
6/21/1951 1:00  1110.68 1439.47 1536.86 1629.83 2045.69 1430.61 909.428
6/22/1951 1:00  1101.07 1386.08 1929    1579.34 2044.79 1384.03 881.96
6/23/1951 1:00  1077.87 1337.32 1953.41 1527.09 2050.25 1345.84 855.904
6/24/1951 1:00  1071.67 1288.9  1880.82 1476.88 2038.62 1376.26 827.653
6/25/1951 1:00  1078.04 1243.48 1862.96 1428.25 2016.73 1492.71 801.002
6/26/1951 1:00  1116.61 1199.91 1798.16 1383.56 1996.23 1438.23 774.804
6/27/1951 1:00  1214.1  1156.82 1961.49 1340.19 1986.9  1389.82 750.454
6/28/1951 1:00  1230.6  1114.48 1890.87 1297.42 1963.9  1366.01 727.893
6/29/1951 1:00  1376.2  1174.09 1820.57 1380.23 1929.55 1320.35 715.91
6/30/1951 1:00  1340.32 1144.34 1763.42 1355.39 1886.8  1278.97 881.508
7/1/1951 1:00   1292.18 1106.3  1739.17 1429.77 1834.12 1240.08 910.984
7/2/1951 1:00   1244.22 1070.49 1895.89 1453.19 1780.86 1254.12 875.708
7/3/1951 1:00   1199.22 1057.07 1895.1  1412.33 1732.32 1348.73 851.163
7/4/1951 1:00   1158.89 1028.51 1827.25 1396.07 1680.39 1295.46 832.093
7/5/1951 1:00   1259.61 994.971 1802.14 1411.81 1624.13 1249.98 851.646
7/6/1951 1:00   1227.98 962.17  1784.4  1377.75 1568.53 1208.88 822.595
7/7/1951 1:00   1197.16 931.445 1766.44 1373.47 1519.12 1182.29 792.594
7/8/1951 1:00   1164.45 909.444 1701.69 1325.09 1474.84 1244.96 763.652
7/9/1951 1:00   1135.29 898.986 1803.29 1281.39 1428.67 1322.78 738.863
7/10/1951 1:00  1094.83 875.32  1933.74 1240.38 1380.09 1582.96 712.016
7/11/1951 1:00  1055.46 847.625 1865    1200.46 1334.61 1612.94 689.9
7/12/1951 1:00  1016.67 818.958 1801.86 1163.41 1290.76 1619.86 702.886
7/13/1951 1:00  977.839 793.202 1745.62 1126.56 1247.5  1701.16 680.056
7/14/1951 1:00  941.782 771.035 1700.33 1090.64 1212.04 1716.81 658.393
7/15/1951 1:00  908.753 752.606 1662.62 1081.28 1183.16 1719.49 639.721
7/16/1951 1:00  877.51  935.476 1601.96 1056.69 1152.2  1676.24 622.633
7/17/1951 1:00  847.928 1330.68 1546.06 1039.49 1171.52 1635.67 631.078
7/18/1951 1:00  819.773 1311.03 1493.5  1047.16 1130.61 1639.27 613.98
7/19/1951 1:00  792.915 1265.12 1460.46 1011.69 1092.57 1588.82 603.208
7/20/1951 1:00  767.243 1222.03 1405.81 1100.74 1091.14 1535.05 584.897
7/21/1951 1:00  742.893 1204.46 1353.82 1383.01 1054.6  1494.58 569.675
7/22/1951 1:00  719.341 1162.33 1306.41 1797.51 1020.15 1543.84 575.738
7/23/1951 1:00  696.562 1123.31 1267.62 1830.11 988.19  1508.21 583.532
7/24/1951 1:00  675.924 1162.78 1223.88 1765.1  1027.7  1473.93 614.682
7/25/1951 1:00  661.057 1124.09 1182.63 1702.59 1014.29 1631.72 612.546
7/26/1951 1:00  679.961 1089.78 1144.22 1652.44 979.729 1584.5  605.722
7/27/1951 1:00  660.791 1102.66 1106.02 1646.82 947.145 1527.02 590.314
7/28/1951 1:00  642.725 1073.56 1070.31 1607.29 915.957 1533.29 596.444
7/29/1951 1:00  663.503 1037.36 1037.07 1550.32 1002.37 1543.77 581.582
7/30/1951 1:00  651.948 1001.29 1007.6  1495.34 1161.34 1490.13 577.83
7/31/1951 1:00  634.32  969.425 1021.05 1441.68 1130.55 1438.28 564.808
8/1/1951 1:00   618.891 947.812 986.323 1390.42 1168.49 1388.32 600.806
8/2/1951 1:00   608.039 938.736 953.7   1341.94 1126.99 1382.47 597.313
8/3/1951 1:00   667.646 923.228 922.387 1296.37 1086.23 1340.56 664.759
8/4/1951 1:00   659.323 893.933 893.014 1251.44 1048.46 1293.14 716.268
8/5/1951 1:00   648.488 1021.82 891.359 1209.35 1011.48 1248.58 703.447
8/6/1951 1:00   632.3   1095.96 1099.22 1170.11 976.161 1204.56 683.621
8/7/1951 1:00   618.085 1092.21 1060.47 1136.43 942.963 1173.48 667.491
8/8/1951 1:00   602.466 1202.22 1021.34 1120.45 968.045 1329.41 653.331
8/9/1951 1:00   587.453 1397.47 985.843 1084.1  1072.01 1292.29 641.894
8/10/1951 1:00  574.043 1354.74 952.957 1047.73 1075.4  1246.04 702.969
8/11/1951 1:00  562.144 1305.1  921.655 1013.37 1059.16 1205.38 683.65
8/12/1951 1:00  584.826 1262.65 893.031 1031.12 1043.81 1161.34 710.367
8/13/1951 1:00  580.844 1257.84 865.607 1112.42 1176.16 1121.24 764.236
8/14/1951 1:00  585.845 1421.38 842.275 1072.94 1140.94 1113.25 760.43
8/15/1951 1:00  1138.93 1392.95 816.628 1036.72 1101.78 1356.95 785.087
8/16/1951 1:00  1215.95 1347.1  792.186 1002.88 1078.93 1381.03 762.678
8/17/1951 1:00  1228.68 1400.36 776.859 974.684 1043.95 1406.93 741.7
8/18/1951 1:00  1202.03 1456.57 780.517 945.327 1004.95 1360.86 722.036
8/19/1951 1:00  1221.12 1497.04 1441.75 915.365 968.521 1315.16 709.169
8/20/1951 1:00  1177.16 1442.68 2503.59 885.85  934.568 1392.11 689.621
8/21/1951 1:00  1134.62 1430.34 3216.34 857.606 904.955 1389.83 669.421
8/22/1951 1:00  1107.93 1658.08 3205.78 828.599 878.469 1355.1  648.328
8/23/1951 1:00  1177.11 1849.94 3136.63 804.99  849.94  1307.36 628.98
8/24/1951 1:00  1210.75 1782.49 3568.05 778.814 821.994 1314.59 612.572
8/25/1951 1:00  1295.35 1717.66 3689.64 754.489 795.893 1300.39 597.613
8/26/1951 1:00  1251.68 1656.24 3549.93 730.701 770.1   1257.26 583.451
8/27/1951 1:00  1240.03 1599.26 3416.38 707.467 745.538 1221.4  569.435
8/28/1951 1:00  1197.23 1546.4  3293.43 683.328 722.857 1378.84 555.525
8/29/1951 1:00  1547.41 1545.26 3168.92 660.238 701.089 1333.38 542.849
8/30/1951 1:00  1728.28 1513.6  3047.83 639.119 680.118 1297.38 531.791
8/31/1951 1:00  1766.99 1480.93 2933.64 620.192 660.585 1497.7  572.11
9/1/1951 1:00   1704.01 1429.12 2824.59 603.568 667.87  1503.94 707.692
9/2/1951 1:00   1642.49 1381.48 2718.47 587.822 666.708 1590.17 691.175
9/3/1951 1:00   1584.37 1529.19 2616.22 573.659 646.888 1606.15 717.891
9/4/1951 1:00   1528.76 2435.63 2519.12 564.207 626.794 1553.98 690.693
9/5/1951 1:00   1477.91 2526.62 2427.44 548.366 607.768 1503.95 667.275
9/6/1951 1:00   1429.65 2460.48 2339.48 534.527 591.769 1455.35 644.975
9/7/1951 1:00   1379.68 2367.86 2251.4  520.936 635.32  1408.65 626.621
9/8/1951 1:00   1337.42 2279.57 2168.13 508.246 738.938 1363.39 610.864
9/9/1951 1:00   1310.15 2194.82 2182.55 496.326 717.112 1318.97 606.687
9/10/1951 1:00  1362.07 2114.32 2341.05 577.235 732.378 1275.26 589.341
9/11/1951 1:00  1311.19 2038.49 2250.21 613.572 891.413 1235.18 571.219
9/12/1951 1:00  1263.63 1988.93 2163.44 594.976 1165.41 1201.35 590.136
9/13/1951 1:00  1219.01 2015.34 2080.34 574.966 1137.85 1295.85 805.509
9/14/1951 1:00  1176    1947.52 2000.65 555.383 1345.26 1453.36 784.49
9/15/1951 1:00  1348.17 1986.12 1924.25 538.544 1373.03 1456.26 753.196
9/16/1951 1:00  1407.16 1987.67 1850.92 522.686 1341.85 1461.8  740.049
9/17/1951 1:00  1352.97 1918.3  1784.72 507.644 1381.03 1424.82 739.127
9/18/1951 1:00  1300.24 1851.96 1719.48 493.712 1332.81 1382.47 734.296
9/19/1951 1:00  1251.78 1818.41 1655.74 482.093 1279.92 1331.31 735.545
9/20/1951 1:00  1209.74 1773.63 1593.72 468.021 1261.64 1456.91 724.446
9/21/1951 1:00  1220.93 1720.97 1533.18 456.96  1448.94 1516.53 713.133
9/22/1951 1:00  1272.48 1665.41 1475.73 462.618 1417.41 1471.87 689.368
9/23/1951 1:00  1489.41 1610.21 1420.79 454.486 1399.06 1419.63 665.089
9/24/1951 1:00  1455.88 1565.02 1369.36 450.532 1365.79 1371.07 642.505
9/25/1951 1:00  1399.38 1825.42 1320.16 436.37  1312.99 1326.89 633.057
9/26/1951 1:00  1345.88 1821.28 1273.55 422.701 1262.5  1282.31 641.853
9/27/1951 1:00  1297.64 1798.47 1230.06 409.991 1215.59 1296.8  622.47
9/28/1951 1:00  1248.31 1737.43 1193.4  397.654 1173.54 1356.49 863.944
9/29/1951 1:00  1201.12 1671.34 1154.54 385.869 1130.01 1322.4  851.795
9/30/1951 1:00  1177.24 1609.89 1112.22 374.125 1322.27 1327.07 1037.18
10/1/1951 1:00  1337.03 1636.4  1072.15 363.148 1411.67 1325.62 1133.13
10/2/1951 1:00  1455.61 1686.06 1033.84 352.513 1357    1480.85 1097.19
10/3/1951 1:00  1401.26 1632.11 997.971 342.329 1304.07 1464.4  1060.2
10/4/1951 1:00  1349.36 1593.73 963.693 333.407 1252.96 1419.1  1041.37
10/5/1951 1:00  1304.61 1690.53 974.593 325.844 1204.73 1369.34 1040.46
10/6/1951 1:00  1503.73 1629.49 1083.65 332.883 1159.53 1390.17 1286.15
10/7/1951 1:00  1452.63 1572.53 1254.7  346.665 1116    1525.06 1349.93
10/8/1951 1:00  1397.48 1516.79 1295.12 343.283 1081.3  1475.07 1304.7
10/9/1951 1:00  1364.34 1465.18 1244.24 335.273 1042.57 1425.42 1282.22
10/10/1951 1:00 1345.87 1412.89 1201.85 326.427 1003.76 1378.69 1243.58
10/11/1951 1:00 1556.76 1365.28 1158.8  319.419 967.089 1334.19 1251.17
10/12/1951 1:00 1622.52 1435.35 1115.58 312.028 932.187 1330.35 1279.36
10/13/1951 1:00 1559.3  1740.66 1076.93 304.311 897.657 1285.1  1259.34
10/14/1951 1:00 1497.79 1797.2  1037.49 295.613 864.375 1240.01 1362.83
10/15/1951 1:00 1438.53 1754    996.624 286.976 832.293 1196.84 1311.05
10/16/1951 1:00 1381.39 1802.59 957.254 278.245 801.206 1227.81 1264.84
10/17/1951 1:00 1326.29 1977.78 919.354 269.129 771.326 1193.09 1349.7
10/18/1951 1:00 1273.49 2054.25 882.291 260.336 742.13  1152.31 1388.61
10/19/1951 1:00 1243.27 2213.24 846.809 283.518 716.694 1112.56 1604.88
10/20/1951 1:00 1196.73 2152.52 812.715 275.463 690.45  1094.78 1634.13
10/21/1951 1:00 1156.28 2088.35 780.482 265.571 664.076 1252.69 1980.99
10/22/1951 1:00 1181.52 2088.54 755.575 387.023 639.827 1303.77 2051.19
10/23/1951 1:00 1297.37 2194.13 1053.06 408.825 617.01  1496.38 2031
10/24/1951 1:00 1273.25 2254.23 1343.25 414.776 593.567 1565.93 1992.94
10/25/1951 1:00 1225.81 2303.93 1790.02 698.869 570.818 1514.79 1993.4
10/26/1951 1:00 1177.79 2314.86 1810.41 745.094 551.133 1466.51 1931.88
10/27/1951 1:00 1131.48 2305.49 1975.2  718.711 593.432 1417.75 1897.26
10/28/1951 1:00 1106.36 2266.15 1909.46 785.008 833.715 1370.91 1869.51
10/29/1951 1:00 1099.63 2192.32 1836.32 766.446 871.919 1326.11 1816.67
10/30/1951 1:00 1056.27 2122.89 1764.18 783.665 845.388 1281.74 1750.55
10/31/1951 1:00 1092.71 2049.84 1694.17 789.255 865.802 1239.33 1688.58
11/1/1951 1:00  1051.45 1976.98 1626.57 803.205 937.158 1198.95 1635.44
11/2/1951 1:00  1019.01 2536.04 1561.51 771.654 972.532 1162.09 1682.51
11/3/1951 1:00  992.959 3107.67 1503.1  740.178 1030.36 1122.17 1726.42
11/4/1951 1:00  957.823 3225.94 1446.05 773.057 1006.08 1079.55 1789.78
11/5/1951 1:00  923.327 3243.1  1388.93 932.497 974.112 1037.47 1724.05
11/6/1951 1:00  897.778 3194.96 1333.58 1241.24 937.399 1057.41 1675.15
11/7/1951 1:00  864.531 3095.29 1279.56 1647.36 902.049 1173.71 1615.02
11/8/1951 1:00  830.17  2992.27 1227.53 1896.88 872.061 1130.72 1645.28
11/9/1951 1:00  797.253 2905.56 1177.53 1877.63 886.442 1117.15 1811.13
11/10/1951 1:00 765.378 2812.67 1129.58 1901.74 892.396 1109.92 2016.75
11/11/1951 1:00 734.53  2765.89 1085.09 1919.89 859.156 1446.19 2098.54
11/12/1951 1:00 704.87  2825.4  1040.86 1900.5  825.958 1487.69 2145.75
11/13/1951 1:00 676.341 2870.66 998.998 2292.35 793.783 1531.13 2080.47
11/14/1951 1:00 648.983 2883.36 958.245 2366.7  762.704 1551.08 2025.29
11/15/1951 1:00 651.493 2786.74 961.035 2353.55 758.36  1512.65 1963.84
11/16/1951 1:00 669.712 2772.17 1069.32 2307.25 999.93  1508.32 1911.36
11/17/1951 1:00 642.692 2946.8  1093.54 2222.23 967.713 1664.88 1847.41
11/18/1951 1:00 643.678 3200.36 1316.71 2160.82 961.368 1614.95 1796.24
11/19/1951 1:00 854.424 3116.74 1320.69 2221.03 1012.97 1563.3  1832.8
11/20/1951 1:00 1563.03 3086.03 1292.69 2612.47 998.855 1525.98 2011.03
11/21/1951 1:00 1580.86 2992.23 1297.54 2621.91 1197.95 1568.79 2523.83
11/22/1951 1:00 1946.56 2898.49 1246.26 2519.94 1163.77 1727.64 2586.63
11/23/1951 1:00 2366.9  2955.77 1299.08 2424.59 1122.32 1900.13 2501.61
11/24/1951 1:00 2276.37 3049.61 1334.81 2330.12 1213.45 1873.76 2536.26
11/25/1951 1:00 3042.13 2996.7  1708.46 2238.45 1302.05 1817.76 2449.33
11/26/1951 1:00 3212.75 2902.17 1650.87 2155.63 1281.74 1756.32 2368.09
11/27/1951 1:00 3122.73 2835.81 1645.35 2108.78 1254.06 1697.16 2560.5
11/28/1951 1:00 3005.82 2961.7  1795.01 2110.4  1204.14 1637.38 2947.31
11/29/1951 1:00 2896.98 3338.51 1725.19 2159.07 1155.98 1578.4  3222.18
11/30/1951 1:00 2793.14 3585.05 1718.76 2072.74 1109.55 1520.36 3155.61
12/1/1951 1:00  2682.34 3605.96 1888.79 1991.87 1064.83 1466.63 3033.16
12/2/1951 1:00  2618.32 3579.53 2025.47 1912.11 1021.78 1505.62 3058.92
12/3/1951 1:00  2602.48 3645.49 2193.76 1951.67 980.367 1900.1  2941.42
12/4/1951 1:00  2663.44 3816.05 2232.83 2463.14 940.548 2062.67 2827.12
12/5/1951 1:00  2717.67 3823.21 2197.52 2533.36 925.483 2353.05 2753.95
12/6/1951 1:00  3022.4  4406.33 2133.36 2465.54 1144.38 2575.91 2840.68
12/7/1951 1:00  3179.75 4386.97 2055.55 2372.34 1125.92 2589.07 2929.75
12/8/1951 1:00  3100.24 4729.88 2055.87 3089.11 1109.17 2547.46 3161.26
12/9/1951 1:00  3231.01 5453.69 1973.78 3117.4  1222.15 2647.79 3443.13
12/10/1951 1:00 3256.51 6614.34 1907.34 3076.11 1503.71 2866.78 4016.1
12/11/1951 1:00 3138.92 6787.98 1856.45 3169.42 2656.42 3022.23 4447.15
12/12/1951 1:00 3117.41 6651.5  1800.68 3520.29 2550.13 2961.92 4500.56
12/13/1951 1:00 3027.87 6505.66 1728.61 3630.58 2446.94 2919.69 4406.75
12/14/1951 1:00 3039.63 6350.8  1660.3  3545.96 2358.74 2884.51 4256.61
12/15/1951 1:00 3054.06 6212.77 1603.51 3414.28 2263.33 2838.38 4112.3
12/16/1951 1:00 3163.15 6043.45 1539.93 3317.81 2171.81 2745.45 3969.58
12/17/1951 1:00 3085.46 5989.27 1477.64 3417.61 2248.6  2652.26 3825.81
12/18/1951 1:00 3075.28 5898.04 1417.82 4683.83 2316.71 2558.16 3684.78
12/19/1951 1:00 3001.68 6053.93 1361.19 4561.67 2675.05 2465.72 3696.66
12/20/1951 1:00 2897.28 6228.51 1308.71 4651.92 3015.03 2700.14 4045.15
12/21/1951 1:00 2792.85 6369.11 1273.93 4774.94 3716.48 3252.89 4617.42
12/22/1951 1:00 2692.7  6267.24 1291.26 4891.21 4441.43 3229.04 5033.28
12/23/1951 1:00 2627.38 6161.77 1252.94 4929.57 4742.74 3119.01 5110.36
12/24/1951 1:00 2529.66 6443.25 1436.21 5099.09 5476.79 3009.34 5307.5
12/25/1951 1:00 2438.99 6629.09 1392.34 4945.93 5313.57 2902.43 5134.8
12/26/1951 1:00 2396.05 6525.34 1407.56 4776.2  5106.1  2798.43 5000.11
12/27/1951 1:00 2305.59 6375.94 1550.93 4607.3  5178.79 2698.32 4825.11
12/28/1951 1:00 2221.16 6234.93 1902.01 4436.96 5160.45 2597.66 4891.27
12/29/1951 1:00 2138.89 6260.16 1871.37 4276.9  5020.48 2504.8  5638.67
```

so far I have plotted the density with ggplot using the code below

```
library(reshape)
newaa <- melt(aa)
ggplot(data = newaa) + geom_density(aes(x = value, color = variable), alpha = 0.2)
```

This results in

[image: density plot]

However, I don't want to show all of them as it makes my plot crowded so I want only the minimum and maximum densities and show only them on my plot. I found that `geom_ribbon` with in ggplot2 does it so I tried to check with this code. `geom_ribbon` requires the min and max arguments. For this first I have to calculated the maximum and minimum densities values from each variable

```
for(i in 1:7){
    d <- density(aa[ , i + 1])
    xx[[i]] <- d$x
    yy[[i]] <- d$y}
k <- c()
g <- c()
l <- c()
for (j in 1: length(yy[[1]])){
    kk <- max(sapply(yy, "[", j)) ## maxm density
    gg <- min(sapply(yy, "[", j)) ## minm density
    ll <- max(sapply(xx,"[",j))   ## xaxis value of the density
    k <- rbind(k, as.numeric(kk))
    g <- rbind(g, as.numeric(gg))
    l <- rbind(l, as.numeric(ll))
}

minmax <- data.frame(cbind(g, k, l))
names(minmax) <- c("min", "max", "x")
ggplot(data=newaa) + 
    geom_density(aes(x = value, color = variable), alpha = 0.2) +
    xlab(expression("flow  " ~~ (m^{3}~s^{-1}))) +
    ylab("Density") +
    ggtitle("PDF") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 
0.5)) +
    geom_ribbon(data = minmax, aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, fill = 
"violetred4",x = x), alpha = 0.3)
```

This results in

[image: merged density plot]

However the figure shifts and its not overlapping with the original density graphs. I think that this happens due to the scaling effect in the x axis(I am here plotting the max and min densities with max value of the variable(l) , which is why the graphs are shifted and elongated). There are other easier options like scaling, I don't want every thing to scale between 0-1, as it will loose the spread of the distribution (since some of the variable has small higher tail and others have high tails). I just want the polygon/Area with min and maxm density. Could any one of you take a look and help me with this. The code I wrote is very inefficient. could you please help me optimize the code in terms of computing time and memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `density` to calculate y-values over a predefined domain for each vector. Using `purrr::map_df` to assemble the results into a data.frame, you can then extract the highest and lowest row easily with `apply` or `pmax`/`pmin`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df[-1] %>%    # exclude `date` column
    map_df(~density(.x, from = 0, to = 7000)$y) %>%    # extract y values of densities over defined domain
    transmute(ymax = apply(., 1, max),    # or do.call(pmax, .)
              ymin = apply(., 1, min),    # or do.call(pmin, .)
              x = seq(0, 7000, length = 512)) %>%    # re-add domain
    ggplot() + 
    geom_ribbon(aes(x, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax), alpha = 0.3) + 
    geom_density(data = gather(df, var, val, -date), aes(val, color = var))
```

[image: plot with ribbon and densities]

If you don't want to hard-code the domain, you could replace 7000 with `max(df[-1])` if you like.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire. This is exactly I want. Now, I need to add the geom_ribbon from another data frame in the same plot to show the shift in the distribution group. I tried by copying the same chunk of code below and removed the ggplot() in the later one as it has been called already. I got error"Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval". I thought of doing this by saving the transmute step and later on calling it to the geom_ribbon, but i don't know how to save the intermediate steps in the loop format (%>%). Could you please let me know how it could be achieved?

Comment: Break the chain before `ggplot`, run that on each data.frame, and combine the results with `bind_rows` with `.id` set to use later as an aesthetic (probably `fill`). Pass that as the data for `ggplot`, and add the extra aesthetic to differentiate. Alternatively, just save both data frames and pass them in to separate `geom_ribbon` calls.